# Why is my tkinter label not being placed before the next call?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this basic app I am working on. Creating a very basic GUI, and I want to display the status of the connection to a server. I want the GUI window to appear, and place a label saying "connecting..." while it is establishing the connection (which can take up to 4-5 seconds) then once the connection is established it changes the text to "connected".

In my connection class, I pass the label variable, and it will change the text to what I want it to say after the connection has been established, but while the app is trying to connect to the server, instead of displaying "connecting..." it is just a blank box with no text, then after the connection is established, the text goes straight to "connected".  Why is my "Connecting....." label not being placed?

```
class app1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

      self.geometry('250x100')
      self.title('title Here')

      conn_label = tk.Label(self, text='Connecting....', font=('Helvetica', 25))
      conn_label.pack(padx=10, pady=25)

      connection_IP = '192.168.1.111'
      connection_ServerName = 'test_server'

      connection(self, connection_IP, connection_ServerName, conn_label)


class connection():
    def __init__(self, controller, ip, servername, label):
        misc connection information here.
        .....
        label.config(text='Connected!', font=('Helvetica', 25))
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = app1()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because when `connection()` is being created,  tkinter `mainloop` does not take the control so it cannot update the widgets.  After `connection()` completes, the text has been changed to `"Connected!"` and so you cannot see `"Connecting ..."`.

Comment: Schedule the connection with `after`.  `self.after(1, connection, connection_IP, connection_ServerName, conn_label)`. This will make it run 1ms later.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy  Thank you, this does do what I want it to do, I am just trying to wrap my head around why/how the first label does not appear before the connection function is called...

Comment: There's nothing to wrap your head around. Your connection script is blocking tkinter from updating. Have you ever been in a conversation, had it interrupted, and had to continue it after the interruption? Well, your connection script is an interruption. Plain and simple.

Comment: Do this: Delete `.mainloop` and run your program. What happens? You get an empty root window that immediately disappears. No matter what you put in `__init__` you will still get an empty root window. From that observation we can make a strong determination. NOTHING except the root window gets created until `mainloop` is hit. You are literally calling your connection script before your `Label` even visibly exists.